# Not recieved a result

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import *

def print_cube(num):
    print('Cube: '.format(num*num*num))

def print_square(num):
    print('Square: '.format(num*num))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = Process(target = print_cube, args = (10,))
    p2 = Process(target = print_square, args = (10,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print('Done!')
```

output:

```
Cube: 
Square: 
Done!
[Finished in 562ms]
```

no result although I code corectly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You string formatting is wrong.

`print('Square: {}'.format(num*num))`
and
`print('Cube: {}'.format(num*num*num))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the positions in the string to format on

You can learn more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

```
from multiprocessing import *

def print_cube(num):
    print('Cube: {}'.format(num*num*num))

def print_square(num):
    print('Square: {}'.format(num*num))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = Process(target = print_cube, args = (10,))
    p2 = Process(target = print_square, args = (10,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print('Done!')
```

Answer (score 1):

`format` requires curly braces within the string for formatting. So you would have to do:

```
def print_cube(num):
    print('Cube: {}'.format(num*num*num))

def print_square(num):
    print('Square: {}'.format(num*num))
```

Or f-strings:

```
def print_cube(num):
    print(f'Cube: {num*num*num}')

def print_square(num):
    print(f'Square: {num*num}')
```

String formatting formats the string into the curly braces, if there are no curly braces it won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `f` string of python so you dont have to worry about such issues.

```
from multiprocessing import *

def print_cube(num):
    print(f'Cube: {num*num*num}')

def print_square(num):
    print(f'Square: {num*num}')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = Process(target = print_cube, args = (10,))
    p2 = Process(target = print_square, args = (10,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print('Done!')
```